Scrolling is not working after refreshing in mobile view
In desktop view the site works really well but whenever i refresh the page after switching to mobile view, scrolling is not working anymore. Is it because of the libraries i have used(GSAP, Locomotive and Shery Js).
Here is the link: https://falguni-mondal.github.io/EcoSpectra/
Tried to scroll in mobile view after refreshing, it should scroll properly

I went through your source code and found an issue in your css fil, more specifically in line 36 of your css file you set overflow to hidden in your body and that gives the behavior you do not want. I fixed the code and opened a pull request you can merge it and the issue will be fixed.
Happy Coding!!

Thank You @Auron for pointing out the bug in my code. I have tried the changes in the local server, and it seems working on mobile emulator presented in windows chrome browser, but still not working on mobile devices, can you please take a deep look on it.
